# Querying GraphQL in MDX returns TypeError props.data... undifned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Using GatsbyJS, I'm trying to query my blog post's frontmatter (MDX) with GraphQL on my hompage that is aslo an MDX file.

I'm following [Gatsby's guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/mdx/writing-pages/) on how to do this but I keep getting the error "TypeError: props.data.allMdx.edges.node is undefined"

Page I want to query on at "scr/pages/index.mdx"

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Container from "../components/container"
import Cards from "../components/cards"

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexPageQuery {
    allMdx(filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "content/posts/"}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

## Recent Posts

<Container>
  {props.data.allMdx.edges.node.frontmatter.map(node => (
    <Cards>
      <h3>{node.title}</h3>
    </Cards>
  ))}
</Container>
```

My gatsby-config.js file:

```js
const remarkPlugins = [require("remark-slug")]

const website = require("./config/website")

const pathPrefix = website.pathPrefix === "/" ? "" : website.pathPrefix

module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: website.pathPrefix,
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: website.url + pathPrefix,
    pathPrefix,
    title: website.title,
    titleAlt: website.titleAlt,
    description: website.description,
    banner: website.logo,
    headline: website.headline,
    siteLanguage: website.siteLanguage,
    ogLanguage: website.ogLanguage,
    author: website.author,
    facebook: website.facebook,
    twitter: website.twitter,
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
    "gatsby-plugin-catch-links",
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: "content",
        path: `${__dirname}/content/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: "posts",
        path: `${__dirname}/content/posts/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [".mdx", ".md"],
        remarkPlugins,
        options: {
          gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
            {
              resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
              options: {
                maxWidth: 1200,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay! I figured out what I was doing wrong. Basically, I realised GraphQL is picky when you query what data. I got the order right and split up the component into a use-post-list.js hook for calling the GraphQL and post-list.js component for mapping out the query.

the hook at use-post-list.js:

```js
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
export const usePostQuery = () => {
  const { allMdx } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query PostQuery {
        allMdx(filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/content/posts/" } }) {
          edges {
            node {
              frontmatter {
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
  return allMdx
}
```

With the hook, I ONLY need to return allMdx. Expanding it to "return allMdx.edges" gave me the 'undefined' error.

And the post-list.js component:

```js
import React from "react"
import { usePostQuery } from "../hooks/use-posts-hook"

const PostList = () => {
  const allMdx = usePostQuery()

  return (
    <div>
      {allMdx.edges.map(postData => (
        <h1>{postData.node.frontmatter.title}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default PostList
```

Here I had to put "edges" before the .map function and "node" after .map and inside the item I want to query.

Now, I can render out the PostList component in an MDX file which is pretty damn awesome!

Ass simple as this:

```
import { jsx, ThemeProvider } from "theme-ui"
import PostList from "../components/post-list"

# Recent Posts
<PostList />
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I haven't used GatsbyJS before. But, I think your map function is getting called before data comes. You can add the following additional condition to see if that helps. Mostly the typeError occurred due to no data.

```
<Container>
  {props.data &&
    props.data.allMdx && 
    props.data.allMdx.edges && 
    props.data.allMdx.edges.node.frontmatter.map(node => (
    <Cards>
      <h3>{node.title}</h3>
    </Cards>
  ))}
</Container>
```

This will help to check if data is coming or no.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried out the code but I'm still getting the same error message. I'm still figuring out the problem and will post if I have made progress.

Comment: Can you share what response you are getting for `pageQuery`?

Comment: I just figured out what I was doing wrong! I'm so happy! I'm writing the solution....